# py2exe gives RuntimeError: Too early to create image

Tags: python, tkinter, py2exe, photoimage

This python27 32bit code runs perfectly in IDLE, but when packaged by py2exe... not so good.  This is not a duplicate of the missing Tk() question. Something else appears to be uninitialized when running the py2exe generated executable, the call at ImageTk.PhotoImage() balks with 'too early to create image':

```
C:\python\python_ui\exe\dist>basic.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "basic.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "PIL\ImageTk.pyo", line 117, in __init__
  File "Tkinter.pyo", line 3367, in __init__
  File "Tkinter.pyo", line 3304, in __init__
RuntimeError: Too early to create image
Exception AttributeError: "'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'" in <bound method PhotoImage.__del__ of <PIL.ImageTk.Ph
otoImage object at 0x02CA3A90>> ignored
```

**basic.py** - very basic example and yes, Tk() is initialized. Also, the module versions appear to match in both IDLE() and the executable version

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()

image = Image.open("background.jpg")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

label = Label(image=photo)
label.image = photo # keep a reference!
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**setup.py** - Here is my py2exe setup, and I run `python setup.py py2exe` to get the executable:

```
import py2exe, sys, os
from distutils.core import setup
from glob import glob

sys.path.append("C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\\VC\\redist\\x86\\Microsoft.VC90.CRT")
sys.argv.append('py2exe')
setup( 
  data_files = [
      ("Microsoft.VC90.CRT", glob(r'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC90.CRT\*.*')),
      ("background.jpg"),
      ],
  options = {         
    'py2exe' : {
        'compressed': 1, 
        'optimize': 2,
        'bundle_files': 3, 
        'dist_dir': 'dist',  
        'dll_excludes': ["MSVCP90.dll"]
        }
    },                   
  zipfile=None, 
  console = [{'script':'user_code.py'}, {'script':'basic.py'}],
)
```

Version Information matches, and printing the image gives same values when run from IDLE() as it does the executable:

- pil 3.4.2
- tkinter $Revision: 81008 $
- PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=179x119 at 0x3DF6A50

Comment: tried rolling pillow back several versions, stopped at 2.5... no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When all else fails, rebuild everything...

1. Uninstall 32bit python27.12
2. install 32bit python27.10 // 12 will probably work too
3. pip install pip
4. pip install Pillow
5. install MSVC9
6. pip install py2exe
7. remove all prior distribution builds from older py2exe
8. regenerate executable

It works!